# Trigger to update a field on every CRUD operation laravel 5 Query Builder

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, crud

I have a situation . I am working on some backend application where i need to track id of last user who has done some changes to data (database CRUD operation).

I am using Query builder for this (because of some issues but yes i followed Query builder overall for application and eloquent is used for user table only ). It is a website where data is more important and we want to track last user who have changed make change to database , I have around 20 tables where data is changing.

Now need is i am looking for some laravel trigger where i will program code at one place and it will update for every CRUD . So whenever data is changing this trigger is updating user's ID . I don't want to code on every CRUD call , So there should be some trigger which can help us here .

As i have not used Eloquent . I know i can use parent::boot method for my parent model and can extend others with this model.

So is there any other way for Query builder . So is there anything that can help. Any help guys?

I am using laravel 5

Answer (score 0):

Laravel does trigger events for db changes, I believe its `illuminate.query` but I have not used this so I may be mistaken.

Comment: OK i will check this as i am not sure though .

Answer (score 0):

L5 fire automagically events in CRUD actions. Even you can hook in various moments in the acction, you get this out of the box in L5:

- creating,
- created,
- updating,
- updated,
- saving,
- saved,
- deleting,
- deleted,
- restoring,
- restored.

See [Model Events](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-events) and [Model Observers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-observers)

For listen the **events for the query builder** you can hook in the `iluminte.query` event.

```
Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query, $params, $time, $conn) 
{ 
    dd(array($query, $params, $time, $conn));
});
```

Also you can listen like this

```
DB::listen(function($squery, $params, $time)
{
   dd(array($query, $params, $time));
});
```

Comment: I am talking about query builder only . No eloquent used , For models we can use parent::boot() which keep track of above listed events .

Comment: I edited my response, maybe you can implement a regexp in `$query` var in the catched event to detect the action type, INSERT, UPDATE, etc.,

Comment: Yes , but it listen for every call , how will i know that i am inserting or updating . Because it listens for all queries like select and all , I need trigger which listen when db changes. Any idea?. Anyway thanks for you help though :)

Comment: Not a very neat one, the $query var is a plain string, you can implement here a regexp to catch the type of query, and then extract the column names you expect, and the values... but this regexp seems to me a little overwhelming...